# php for loop with foreach textarea

Tags: php, html, for-loop, foreach, textarea

I need get line by line data from textarea and group it for three cointainers. How to fix it?

My code

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php">
  <textarea name="textarea" style="width:100%; height: 20vh"></textarea><br /><br />
  <input type="submit" class="button" style="float: right; cursor:pointer;" value="">
 </form>

 <?php

$lines = explode("\n", $_POST['textarea']);
if ( !empty($lines) ) {

  foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
    for ($i=1;$i<=3;$i++) {
    echo trim( $line )."<br/>";
  }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to check if POST not null first... because POST is null able...
Seems textarea will be encode html...
so could you try to change

```
// '\n' to '<br>' or '</br>' !


if(trim($_POST['textarea'])!=null){
$lines = explode("\n", $_POST['textarea']); //or change '\n' to <br>  or </br> if this not working

if ( $lines != null) ) {
    $i=0;
  foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
    if( !empty(trim($line)) ){
      $i++;
    if($i<=3) {
    echo trim( $line )."<br/>";
    }
  }
  }

}
}
```

Comment: so sorry i replay by phone so i got a lot misstake... but i think it's working for you.